# EDMX update model from database Timeout

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, edmx-designer

I have a MSSQL DB with about 3300tables (don't ask why, that's Nav...).
When I try to "Update Model from Database..." on my EDMX I am getting a timeout exception 99 times out of 100.
So my question is, is there anyway to change the timeout?
I have tried to set "Connect Timeout" in the connection string, but it doesn't change anything.

I also tried to create a SQL account with an access on only the tables I need (about 10) but the timeout in the wizard still occur.

Comment: Do you REALLY need 3300 tables in the same EDMX file? Which SQL Server and EF versions and EF Tools versions do you use?

Comment: I didn't say my EDMX had 3300 tables, I said the DB have 3300 tables, the timeout occur when the wizard try to get the list of the tables from the DB. So I am not even able to add a table to my EDMX. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Ah, OK. No, connection timeout doesn't help. And command timeout can't be set in the connection string. Is it an option to switch to "code first" (but not really, i.e. no migrations)? You'd have to sync the EF model manually when the database changes. Usually that's not too complicated. (Also, native edmx support will disappear in EF 7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone at work just helped me with this.

1. Run a SQL profiler and try to update your model again.
2. Capture the SQL Query that Visual Studio trys to run. It should look something like this

   ```
   SELECT 
   [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
   [Project1].[CatalogName] AS [CatalogName], 
   [Project1].[SchemaName] AS [SchemaName], 
   [Project1].[Name] AS [Name]
   FROM ( SELECT 
       [Extent1].[CatalogName] AS [CatalogName], 
       [Extent1].[SchemaName] AS [SchemaName], 
       [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
       1 AS [C1]
       FROM (
       SELECT
       quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA) + quotename(TABLE_NAME) [Id]
       ,   TABLE_CATALOG [CatalogName]
       ,   TABLE_SCHEMA [SchemaName]
       ,   TABLE_NAME    [Name]
       FROM
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
       WHERE
       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
     ) AS [Extent1]
   )  AS [Project1]
   ORDER BY [Project1].[SchemaName] ASC, [Project1].[Name] ASC
   ```
3. Then run the query in SS Managment Studio. When you run the query the results should be cached. When Visual Studio runs the query again the results should come back really quick and it won't time out.

Answer (score 0):

A small work around :

- Generate an sql script to create only the tables you need from the DB
- Create another DB and execute the sql script
- Generate the EDMX from this new DB
- Change the connection string of the EDMX to connect to the first DB